# How to word with UISearchBar Delegate and an array?

Tags: objective-c, swift, uitableview, delegates, uisearchbar

I want to implement a `UIsearchBar` with an array.  I have an array with city names.  How do I implement it with a table view?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you should set the delegate of `UISearchBar` and to create an other `NSMutableArray` with filtered results. The dataSource for your `UITableView` will now release uppon this new array.

Then, add the delegate method like this :

```
-(void)searchBar:(UISearchBar*)searchBar textDidChange:(NSString*)text {
    filteredTableData = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    for (Food* food in allTableData)
    {
        NSRange nameRange = [food.name rangeOfString:text options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch];
        NSRange descriptionRange = [food.description rangeOfString:text options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch];
        if(nameRange.location != NSNotFound || descriptionRange.location != NSNotFound)
        {
            [filteredTableData addObject:food];
        }
    }
    [self.tableView reloadData];
}
```

For the full code, see here : [Filtering a UITableView with a search bar](http://code-ninja.org/blog/2012/01/08/ios-quick-tip-filtering-a-uitableview-with-a-search-bar/)

Hope this helps.

Comment: i see that full code but not understanding, what is "food" . is this any kind of typedef from any data type or class.

Comment: Sorry for not including all informations. Food is the (custom) type of the object stored in your array. Assuming your storing city names, your type is probably NSString. Replace Food with NSString. If you provide some code I would help you further.

Comment: Hey, this is my table view and i wanna search states from responseArr. ..

Comment: NSString *city = [[responseArr valueForKey:@"city"]objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];